# background-image is not working for select option in Firefox above 48 version and other browsers

Tags: html, css, background-image, select-options

I wanted output like :

Output for Firefox version 48 and its below versions :

[image]

Firefox higher versions (above 48) & other browsers :

[image]

Code :

```
<select style="padding-left: 25px; background: no-repeat url(yellow.png) 4px 1px">
  <option style="padding-left: 25px; background-image: url(blue.png);" value="116">Blue</option>
  <option style="padding-left: 25px; background: url('red.jpg') 4px 1px;" value="118">Red</option>
  <option style="padding-left: 25px; background: url('green.jpg') 4px 1px;" value="119">Green</option>
  <option style="padding-left: 25px; background: url(yellow.png) 4px 1px; background-attachment: scroll;" value="120" selected="selected">Yellow</option>
  <option style="padding-left: 25px; background: url(orange.jpg) 4px 1px" value="121">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Want to display first output in Firefox higher version and other browsers.

- I can't use JQuery or bootstrap in this project.
- Also can't use other than form element.

Do anyone knows, how to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `url('./yellow.png')` or `url('../yellow.png')` instead of `url(yellow.png)`, depending where your image is located.